# PHP with mySQl : Making a query that user chooses what fields to fill out each time

Tags: php, mysql

First time using PHP and also first time using mySQL so if i'm making an any errors please point them out.

I would like to be able to get data from my table which isn't the problem, I would like the user to **fill out as many textBoxes or as little texts boxes as they would like** and return all the data that is relevant to their search?

I have these variables

```
 //get variables from page before  
$ProductName = $_POST["ProductName"];  
$ProductCategory = $_POST["ProductCategory"]; 
$ProductAge = $_POST["ProductAge"]; 
$ProductDis = $_POST["ProductDis"]; 
$ProductPrice = $_POST["ProductPrice"];
$ProductInStock = $_POST["ProductInStock"];
```

and would like some kind of query like (if possible something else)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE such and such ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your query dynamically.

For example for the price (using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$vars = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE 1";    // using WHERE 1 just for the example
...
if (!empty($_POST["ProductPrice"]))
{
  $query .= " AND ProductPrice <= :ProductPrice";
  $vars[':ProductPrice'] = $_POST["ProductPrice"];
}
...
// prepare query
// execute query with the $vars array
```

The conditions depend on you, I just took the price to be the maximum for this example.

Comment: The generated query will be `SELECT * FROM Produce WHERE AND ...`

Comment: @GordonM I just realized that and added a dummy condition. Not something I would do myself, but just to make it work here without going into too much details...

Comment: @GordonM Thanks, the question is too broad to get into specific details anyway, this is just supposed to be a pointer.

Comment: you need to check if each $_POST parameter isn't empty, if it has any value, you append AND clauses to your query and then you run it, GordonM's solution is good but I'd label my $_POST variables as an array like $_POST['data']['ProductName'] so I can only check $_POST['data'] array and ignore other $_POST variables that might affect my query

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick replies will look into your solution now and let you know :)